# How to load managed DLL in c++?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, unmanaged, managed

I try use this [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736) to create in C# DLL and use it in C++, but example don't work.
Always getting error:

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in
>   CPPClient.exe Additional information: External component has thrown an
>   exception."

Now my question is: How to right load managed DLL in c++? (links, tutorials, advice in that field will be appreciate)

Comment: You did something *very* wrong to get a managed exception in a C++ program.  Impossible to guess what that might be with nothing to look at.  COM has a learning curve, diagnosing runtime failure requires experience, the kind you can only get by getting it wrong a lot of times.  You just got started :)

Comment: You just got started :) -> he he nice to here that :), you have right something i did wrong